# How to take a concat String from column as a Dictionary_Name in dictGet function

Tags: clickhouse

I build a dynamic Dictionary in ClickHouse DB. It will create the dictionary before the SQL commands execute. Also, the dictionary name was created at the same time.

The dictionary name was a combined string by date and table name. Because I don't want to keep so much data in the long-term dictionary, the short-term Dictionary could be a great help to release the memory after maybe an hour when no one is using it.

And the error happened.

When I use the dictionary in my SQL commands it is okay with solid commands.
e.g.
`dictGet(CONCAT('2022-04-06', 'MyTableName'), 'GetBackColumnName',myKeyColumn) AS col_name`

But when I change to using the column from Table, it was broken.
e.g.
`dictGet(CONCAT(DATE_COL, 'MyTableName'), 'GetBackColumnName',myKeyColumn) AS col_name`

And the error message shows up.

> Illegal type String of the first argument of function dictGet,
> expected a const string.

Does anyone know how to fix the issue?

My CH version is: 20.8.7.15

I try to find the resolution from the ClickHouse office report but nothing can fix this issue. And I tried lots of functions of String to figure out what happened.

Comment: dynamic Dictionary ? What is dynamic Dictionary ?

Comment: The whole idea about Dictionaries is that they are always precomputed and stored in memory

Comment: dictGet accepts only constant string and you can do nothing about it.

Comment: I modified the description, the long-term dictionary and the short-term dictionary were much better to describe my thought.